# Create unique order number in sequence in java?

Tags: java

I need to generate a unique order number in sequence for each request. I need to make sure even after JVM restart it should be unique(i mean it should not match to any number before JVM crash)

Best I could think of using database sequence which will give me a unique number in sequence.

Is there any alternative to database sequence in java?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: so that when a custom request comes in , i generate the unique order number

Comment: OK, but where are the previous requests stored? Databse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to guarantee uniqueness is to persist the state of the "unique number generator" so that even if you restart the JVM or if you start more than one JVM, a previously used number won't be picked.

The easiest way is to delegate the unqieu number generation to a database. Alternatively you could generate the numbers sequentially and store the last number in a file (but due to potential data race you need to properly lock the file).

If occasional (but low probability) collision is ok you can use UUID (UUIDs typically use timestamps so it is possible that the same ID be picked twice if two JVMs don't have their clocks synchronized).

Comment: Even if two jvm clock is synchronized, there is probability that generated number is same. Is n't it?

Comment: @user3198603 probably - that was just one example of why you may get duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to persist that number in an database, especially if you might scale to multiple servers. However, you could likely get away with the following in a single server environment:

```
public class UniqueSeq {

    private static final AtomicLong sequence = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

    public static long getNext() {
        return sequence.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not? It starts counting at the timestamp of the reboot.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since "midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC." *Not* since the previous reboot.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I didn't say "since the previous reboot". I said "at the timestamp of the reboot".

Comment: How  safe is this given multiple actors calling that method?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the previously generated numbers, you can take it the optimistic way. Say for instance that this is a database, you can do the following algorithm:

1. generate a random id;
2. insert into table;
3. if error is "id already exists", goto 1; otherwise fail;
4. done.

Limit the number of repetitions of the loop too; and change the strategy. For instance, start with a max id of 100; after 3 tries, if it fails, raise to 1000; then 10000; etc etc. This max number may also be stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look ad [java UUID generator,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) it should be safe to generate unique numbers

If you need to retrieve values *after generation* I think using db solution is the best candidate so you can save them to db

Comment: uuid won't be will be unique till one instance of jvm exist. Number may not be really unique after jvn restart right?

Comment: Based on my experience numbers are unique after jvm restart and *universally unique* definition should enfoces this experience

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, the current timestamp in milliseconds would also work? I'm aware of the fact that this MAY return the same number twice, so this solution really depends on the use case.

If a timestamp won't work and as you need a unique number even after JVM restart you'll need some kind of persistence like a DB or a simple Text file to store the used numbers or the last index (if you're just incrementing it).